# Why mounts are shared on Ubuntu 15.04, and how to turn it off?

Tags: 15.04, automount

This breaks unshare(CLONE_NEWNS), and feels like leftover from some testings.

Ubuntu 15.04:

```
nir@reed:~$ grep '/ / ' /proc/self/mountinfo 
21 0 8:5 / / rw,relatime shared:1 - ext4 /dev/disk/by-uuid/70f9850c-8ebd-4881-a504-e14ec8d37f66 rw,discard,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
```

Ubuntu 14.10:

```
nir@pilgrim:~$ grep '/ / ' /proc/self/mountinfo 
21 0 8:1 / / rw,relatime - ext4 /dev/disk/by-uuid/1d8ff8a8-6026-48dd-b6ce-e52b46c1f33d rw,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
```

Comment: Probably done by the new systemd but I couldn't figure out where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may "feel" like "leftover from some testings", but it is not.  It's a deliberate design choice by Lennart Poettering, made nearly three years ago in order to make systemd's containerization work. The intent was that if one wanted a private `/` mount one used a (future) `/etc/fstab` setting for it.

Note that those `fstab` options came about in those intervening years and now exist.  One could also, alternatively, use them in an explicit `/etc/systemd/system/-.mount` unit.

See [Poettering's own explanation](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/commit/?id=b3ac5f8cb98757416d8660023d6564a7c411f0a0).

## Further reading

- Karel Zak.  [`mount`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man8/mount.8.html). 8.  Ubuntu version 14 manual pages.
- Lennart Poettering.  [`systemd.mount`](http://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html).  systemd manual pages.  freedesktop.org.
- Lennart Poettering.  [`systemd-remount-fs.service`](http://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-remount-fs.service.html).  systemd manual pages.  freedesktop.org.